# How to make the background of bottom sheet dialog transparent in android studio

Tags: java, android-bottomsheetdialog

im currently practicing the bottom sheet dialog element in android studio. My question is how can i get rid of the white area in corners?

thats my bottomsheetdialogfragment class codes

```
public class BottomSheet extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
    public BottomSheet() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottomsheet, container, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

i would like to show you guys the problem but for some reason i cant upload photos.